# JavaScript Same Event on Multiple Methods

Tags: javascript

window.addEventListener("mousemove", rotate);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", getAngle);

Here I am adding the same event to different methods. I found out that my getAngle method runs only once when I move the mouse but my rotate method is fine. Is the above code legal; does it add the same event to both methods?

Comment: Why don't you call `getAngle` inside `rotate`?

Comment: when do you expect a method bound to a "mousemove" event to be triggered, other than when the "mouse" "moves"?

Comment: They will both run, just `rotate` will always be called first.

Comment: Well, if you add rotate first, then it will always be called first.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above code legal; does it add the same event to both methods?

Yes it is. The functions will be called in the order you added them as event listeners. In the case of:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", rotate);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", getAngle);
```

Each time `mousemove` is fired `rotate` will be called first, then `getAngle` is called second.

---

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/mceqaxdj/) demonstrating that each function gets called each time the event is triggered, and shows the order of the calls in the console.